# how can i make AWS continuously read a csv file from my pc and store the data?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, cloud

i'm currently struggling with on how can i make this work i'v watched and read on similar things they talked about lambda function and kinesis and using boto3 , but i haven't found my solution, now to my problem.
i have a python code on my raspberry pi when i run it it gives me a csv file with values and continuously append every value to that file with 0.2 sec delay for every iteration . i want aws to read every new line and store it so i can represent these data as a chart in real time. thank you.

Comment: This is quite broad. Can't you have your Python program upload the file? Or use a different Python program? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate architecture would probably be:

- Program the Raspberry Pi to send the data to the **AWS IoT (Internet of Things)** service
- Write a program (eg in JavaScript) that retrieves the IoT data and visualizes it

There are various libraries available to send the data to the IoT service (ranging from an MQTT client through to the complete boto3 AWS SDK if your device is running Linux). The IoT service is designed to receive this type of "sensor" data and make it available for processing.

There is nothing in AWS to "read" data on another system unless you run a program somewhere to do so. The better approach is to send the data to AWS IoT.

You could then [Visualize AWS IoT Analytics Data with QuickSight - AWS IoT Analytics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotanalytics/latest/userguide/visualization.html), but I don't think this is "real-time" charting. For that, you'll need to write your own code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by John, program your RaspberryPi to use AWS IoT services. This way you will have a working solution with minimum code deployments in AWS.

If you want to write some code and love light deployments then try to expose your Lambda function(s) inserting data into AWS Kinesis service (Real time data/video stream service) via API gateway. This way your Raspberry PI will stream data in almost real time into AWS.

Here are the links for your reference:

https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/

https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis-create-package.html

I hope this is helpful.